# Count number of tags in a XAML file

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing

I have a XAML file where the tags are something like these:

```
<ActorName Name="Nancy" Enabled="False"> 
<ActorName Name="Shivani" Enabled="True">
```

I have attached the code below which are counting these tags but I am not able to sum it up. How to return the sum of all the tags which have `Enabled="True">`?

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder;

        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc=builder.parse("C:\\Users\\nprabhasini\\Desktop\\ShivaSoft.xml");

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("ActorName");

            for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++)
            {
                printNodeInfo(nodes.item(i));
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static void  printNodeInfo(Node node)
    { 

        if(node.hasAttributes())
        {
            NamedNodeMap rootAtt = node.getAttributes();

            for(int i=0;i<rootAtt.getLength();i++)
            {  

                String s1=rootAtt.item(i).getNodeValue();
                if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("True"))
                {
                    i++;
                    System.out.println(i);      
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static String nodeType(short type) {

        switch(type) {
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:               return "Element";
            case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:             return "Attribute";
        }

        return "Unidentified";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple XPath-1.0 expression like

```
count(//ActorName[@Enabled='True'])
```

with Java. Simply adjust the `XPathExpression` below to your needs. Of course, the filename could be `sample.xaml` or similar.
This is the sample code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("sample.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbFactory.setValidating(false);
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
            dBuilder=dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String XPathExpression = "count(//ActorName[@Enabled='True'])"; 
            // Get the count of the elements with the given properties
            Number cnt = (Number)xPath.compile(XPathExpression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
            // Convert the Float value to an int value and output
            System.out.println("Items: "+cnt.intValue());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please help me with one more programme?

Comment: You still haven't accepted this answer. Accept it and then ask a new question with a good [mcve]. That's the way how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: I have a sample text file contains the list of file names and its locations. How should i retrieve the data of all the files present in sample txt file.

Comment: Using the below code: 

public class test3 {
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader main = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\nancy\\Desktop\\kbc.txt"));
        String next = main.readLine();
        while(next!= null)
        {
        BufferedReader sub = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(next));
        String subnext= sub.readLine();
        while (subnext!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(subnext);
            subnext= sub.readLine();
        }
        next = main.readLine();
        }

    }
}